# Surly Disc Trucker with STI Shifters

Tags: touring-bikes

I like the feel of Surly's Disc Trucker, 3x10.

http://surlybikes.com/bikes/disc_trucker/bike_specs

But I want STI shifters, not bar-ends.  Moving to STI would seem to screw up the brake pull; duly noted.

Two questions:

- Will STI shifters work with the front derailleur?  (Sora Triple)
- Will STI shifters work with the rear derailleur?  (XT 10-speed)

Guessing yes (front) and not at all (rear).

It looks like a 9-speed XT RD would work and give me all ten in the back??

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that Surly went with Avid BB7 Mtn+ Tektro RL520 rather than Avid BB7 road + Tektro RL340. The MSRP is higher on the road brake by quite a bit, but at retail the prices are quite close these days (in fact, at JensonUSA, the road combo is 5 USD cheaper), so unless OEM pricing is very different, it seems like an annoying way to cut costs given the amount of people who would be interested in swapping to STI these days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a 3 x 10 STI shifter, the front (Sora) shifter will work fine. For the rear, you're going to need to replace it with a 10 speed Shimano road rear derailleur or a 7-9 speed Shimano rear derailleur due to the change in cable pull (7-9 speed and 10 speed road use the same cable pull in Shimano. 10 speed mountain does something else). Note that the bar ends spec'd on the Disc Trucker are Microshift BS-M10, which are specifically designed for 10 speed mountain cable pull. You can use the [JTek Shiftmate 6](http://jtekengineering.com/products/shiftmate-straight/) as an alternative to putting a 7-9 speed or 10 speed Road Shimano rear derailleur, but I'd recommend against it since its one more place the cable can be damaged, and it will cost more than buying a 9 speed Deore rear derailleur (which is what I'd do to save some cash rather than buying the 9 speed XT, unless you have it laying around or can get it for very cheap).

As for brakes, the Tektro RL520's are for linear pull (V-brakes / mountain disc brakes). This means that the Disc Trucker is outfitted with the Avid BB7 Mountain disc brake calipers. So, if you want to switch to STI brakes, you can either swap out the brake calipers for road brake calipers (e.g. Avid BB7 Road) or use a [Travel Agent](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/travel_agents/), which is a pulley that switches the cable pull between short and long pull brakes. These increase cable wear at the pulley so you have to check them every so often to see the cable is in good condition. Travel agents may be a bit cheaper (two of them should run about 50 USD), but I'd probably opt for the new calipers since it removes one failure point in your brake system (two brakes with rotors will probably run about 100 USD; less if you can find them without rotors). Hayes and Tektro/TRP make disc brakes with short pull (such as the Hayes Comp CX) which you can also use.

Comment: This is entiriely disappointing.  All of my snowbikes have run DuraAce bar end shifters mounted on Paul Thumbies with XTR drivetrain components.  Admittedly the newest one is 4+ years old now.  I guess that setup won't be possible going forward.  What a horrible move from Shimano.  I guess it will be possible to find some other company making thumb shifters compatible with XTR stuff, but jeez what a pain.

Comment: Well, you can use the Microshift 10 speed shifter. But its getting quite tricky to keep track of all the combinations you need to get these things to work...

Comment: Those Microshift SL-M10s look like they'd work, but no idea how you would mount them.  I am pretty sure they are not like the DuraAces and the Paul website is down.

Comment: I'm going to give a shiftmate a try on the rear (already ordered one), and if that goes awry, try a 9-speed deore or xt RD.

Comment: And while I'm okay with another failure point for my shifter, I'm not really okay with another failure point for brakes.  Probably will swap them with BB7 Road.  (Thank you for the sanity check!)

Comment: @ChrisinAK - The SL-M10's just clamp to your bar; they're just regular old thumb shifters with front friction and back as 10 speed Shimano mountain indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Shimano rear derailleurs are mostly interchangeable (except for [older Dura Ace](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/dura-ace.html)) since the 6 speed days.  With a few exceptions, you can pair any Shimano rear derailleur with any Shimano shifter.  The 9 speed XT rear derailleur will work fine with 10 speed shifters.

(Edit: Looks like the Dyna-Sys rear derailleur is probably not compatible, but 9 speed should be fine.  I have not used Dyna-Sys.)

The left/front Shimano shifter is designed for either two chainrings or three, so you just have to pick one or the other.

Regarding the brakes, the original Tektro RL520 levers on the Trucker are designed for linear pull, which is nice because it lets you choose from the larger selection of disc brakes designed for mountain bikes.  But you can also purchase disc brakes [designed for road brake levers](https://www.sram.com/avid/products/bb7-road-mechanical-disc-brake), which will work with the STI brake lever without modification.